# How to duplicate the lines and replace multiple string in ONE Tab Separated File

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a incoming file like (**in.txt**) which is a Tab Separated File and **NO** Header line in it.
I want to duplicated each row TWO times and do the replacement (**base on the rule**s).
I am new in *nux, i am totally no idea what tools can help me to do this.

**The Incoming file (*in.txt*. Separated by Tab(\t))**

```
A       B                C               D               E                      F       G       H 
1   855211046    2/3/2015    $170.00     4154245328852953   328573  1809    CC786875287728777
2   855211046    3/3/2015    $100.10     5524415875875844   822409  1809    CC150330106885244
3   855211046   30/3/2015    $105.00     4875875852875211   445092  1809    CC456387885245062
etc.
```

**The Expected Outcome (*Outcome.txt*)**

```
^2.{32}(855211046000).{8}(150302)
^5(855211046000).{7}(4154245328852953   ).{60}(150302)(328573).{10}\s{1}(000000017000)
^5(855211046000).{7}(4154245328852953   ).{60}(150302)(328573).{122}(000000017000)

^2.{32}(855211046000).{8}(150303)
^5(855211046000).{7}(5524415875875844   ).{60}(150303)(822409).{10}\s{1}(000000010010)
^5(855211046000).{7}(5524415875875844   ).{60}(150303)(822409).{122}(000000010010)

^2.{32}(855211046000).{8}(150330)
^5(855211046000).{7}(4875875852875211   ).{60}(150330)(445092).{10}\s{1}(000000010500)
^5(855211046000).{7}(4875875852875211   ).{60}(150330)(445092).{122}(000000010500)
```

**Rules**

```
*1st record*
^2.{9}.{7}.{16}([Column B's data, 0 fill right till the position 12]).{8}([Column C's data but reformat to YYMMDD format])
^5([Column B's data, 0 fill right till the position 18]).{7}([Column E's data, SPACE fill right till the position 19]).{60}([Column C's data but reformat to YYMMDD format])([Column F's data]).{10}\s{1}([Column D's data but remove $ sign and then multiplied by 100])
^5([Column B's data, 0 fill right till the position 18]).{7}([Column E's data, SPACE fill right till the position 19]).{60}([Column C's data but reformat to YYMMDD format])([Column F's data]).{122}([Column D's data but remove $ sign and then multiplied by 100])

*2nd record*
same as 1st

*3rd record*
same as 1st
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What have you tried ? Also you do have an idea of what tools can help you as you have tagged them in the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not difficult but require attention and some typewriting:

```
awk '
/./{
split($3,T,"/")
$3=sprintf("%d%02d%02d",T[3]-2000,T[2],T[1])
sub("\\$","",$4);$4*=100

printf "^2.{9}.{7}.{16}(%d%0."12-length($2)"d).{8}(%d)\n",$2,0,$3
printf "^5(%d%0."18-length($2)"d).{7}(%-19d).{60}(%d)(%d).{10}\\s{1}(%012d)\n",$2,0,$5,$3,$6,$4
...
}' in.txt >Outcome.txt
```

I am sure that you easyly add `printf` for 3rd line output according to above example.